# Error al instalar la carpeta node_modules | TypeScript react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

como estan? queria comentarles que cuando abro un proyecto de mi trabajo por github desktop para abrir el codigo en vscode, cuando quiero poner npm install, la linea de instalacion se queda por la mitad y despues me tira un error de timeout, luego no me deja instalar paquetes y tampoco me funcion el npm run dev
[image: error al instalar node modules] [image: error al ejecutar la app][image: configuracion de vite][image: node modules en color gris]

Comment: Qué versión de Nodejs estás usando? Dale `node -v`, si estás usando una versión inferior a la 16.14.0, instala la 16.14.0 en tu computadora y asegúrate que cuando corras `node -v` aparezca dicha versión.

Comment: Puedes probar varias cosas: - [Acelerar el tiempo de descarga](http://www.tiernok.com/posts/2019/faster-npm-installs-during-ci/) - `npm cache clean --force` - Actualizar versión de Node, si no sabes que version necesitas puedes checar [acá](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node?activeTab=versions) - Si tienes conexión lenta o inestable tal vez [esto](https://dev.to/devtonight/how-to-fix-npm-timeout-errors-on-slow-internet-connections-2kn4) pueda ayudar.

Comment: También habría que ver de dónde estás tomando los paquetes de npm

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo pude solucionar, al tener la carpeta dentro de "Documents" de mi pc, esto no me permitia instalar las cosas que necesitaba asi que movi todo al escritorio y funciono sin problemas